Docker image's sha256 not deterministic after docker system prune
I don't understand why I get different sha256 hashes when rebuilding after a docker system prune -a. I thought those sha256 hashes were supposed to be deterministic.
Here is my test Dockerfile:
FROM crops/yocto:ubuntu-20.04- 
base@sha256:70d6ce387ae1f87ba52903f7ec7c7d08134de2d97cbf33f8f5b3ef693f2141ea  

RUN mkdir /tmp/foobar

I run the following commands in a directory containing only this Dockerfile, on Ubuntu 24.4 using docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b (which uses BUILDKIT per default):
ecordonnier@lj8k2dq3:~/tmp123$ docker build .
[+] Building 32.0s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                        docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 171B                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/crops/yocto:ubuntu-20.04-base@sha256:70d6ce387ae1f87ba52903f7ec7c7d08134de2d97cbf33f8f5b3ef693f2141ea                                                                                                   1.4s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/crops/yocto:ubuntu-20.04-base@sha256:70d6ce387ae1f87ba52903f7ec7c7d08134de2d97cbf33f8f5b3ef693f2141ea                                                                                                                    29.3s
 => => resolve docker.io/crops/yocto:ubuntu-20.04-base@sha256:70d6ce387ae1f87ba52903f7ec7c7d08134de2d97cbf33f8f5b3ef693f2141ea                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:a2d45245a4b12191026b0c39208107aa1cf1e9c142c3f647ae011dfa383c0995 995B / 995B                                                                                                                                                         0.4s
 => => sha256:70d6ce387ae1f87ba52903f7ec7c7d08134de2d97cbf33f8f5b3ef693f2141ea 1.37kB / 1.37kB                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:a8626b24f89bdeb1a71d0565ec8fb7543d899a0e972d3dc89d594729bc1bd645 4.09kB / 4.09kB                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:3823320faa42774534fd7eee0bd245af8cec6a720ad722144d40efa229291d8f 27.51MB / 27.51MB                                                                                                                                                   1.0s
 => => sha256:77d1ed2b12f544b45374b498afe9c19b0fa13e347937dc4fde2c45e35dea19af 338.57MB / 338.57MB                                                                                                                                                 7.1s
 => => sha256:48c7067512a645c4cc70a6dda6d41119c7927d074c4ac514c65cc82beaf2026d 21.07MB / 21.07MB                                                                                                                                                   1.2s
 => => sha256:4f4fb700ef54461cfa02571ae0db9a0dc1e0cdb5577484a6d75e68dc38e8acc1 32B / 32B                                                                                                                                                           1.2s
 => => extracting sha256:3823320faa42774534fd7eee0bd245af8cec6a720ad722144d40efa229291d8f                                                                                                                                                          1.8s
 => => extracting sha256:77d1ed2b12f544b45374b498afe9c19b0fa13e347937dc4fde2c45e35dea19af                                                                                                                                                         20.0s
 => => extracting sha256:a2d45245a4b12191026b0c39208107aa1cf1e9c142c3f647ae011dfa383c0995                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:48c7067512a645c4cc70a6dda6d41119c7927d074c4ac514c65cc82beaf2026d                                                                                                                                                          1.1s
 => => extracting sha256:4f4fb700ef54461cfa02571ae0db9a0dc1e0cdb5577484a6d75e68dc38e8acc1                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [2/2] RUN mkdir /tmp/foobar                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.4s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.3s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.2s
 => => writing image sha256:40f6b002363ddc9ea22c1f64f17870bb4114304646080425d6b31c185468d88c                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
ecordonnier@lj8k2dq3:~/tmp123$ docker system prune -a
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all images without at least one container associated to them
  - all build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Images:
deleted: sha256:40f6b002363ddc9ea22c1f64f17870bb4114304646080425d6b31c185468d88c

Deleted build cache objects:
6bu7a9gc4i9660hklsuqapa14
l3o61460nsv8md1gd9f6meehz
m31fbjs9lngktkvtm18g87utq
xtepw3cgd6phe1iicdxjqlrne
sa0l1y1elvgjxs3wtlc6mwmiz
w0lxhorjs2zfe32qlxy2w6tze
vr7brv65hx8a6q8din20nc4oi
ymm8j8wp99m4ywy0qc00jeal5

Total reclaimed space: 132B
ecordonnier@lj8k2dq3:~/tmp123$ docker build .
[+] Building 33.0s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                        docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 171B                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/crops/yocto:ubuntu-20.04-base@sha256:70d6ce387ae1f87ba52903f7ec7c7d08134de2d97cbf33f8f5b3ef693f2141ea                                                                                                   0.8s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/crops/yocto:ubuntu-20.04-base@sha256:70d6ce387ae1f87ba52903f7ec7c7d08134de2d97cbf33f8f5b3ef693f2141ea                                                                                                                    30.9s
 => => resolve docker.io/crops/yocto:ubuntu-20.04-base@sha256:70d6ce387ae1f87ba52903f7ec7c7d08134de2d97cbf33f8f5b3ef693f2141ea                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:77d1ed2b12f544b45374b498afe9c19b0fa13e347937dc4fde2c45e35dea19af 338.57MB / 338.57MB                                                                                                                                                 8.8s
 => => sha256:a2d45245a4b12191026b0c39208107aa1cf1e9c142c3f647ae011dfa383c0995 995B / 995B                                                                                                                                                         0.4s
 => => sha256:70d6ce387ae1f87ba52903f7ec7c7d08134de2d97cbf33f8f5b3ef693f2141ea 1.37kB / 1.37kB                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:a8626b24f89bdeb1a71d0565ec8fb7543d899a0e972d3dc89d594729bc1bd645 4.09kB / 4.09kB                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:3823320faa42774534fd7eee0bd245af8cec6a720ad722144d40efa229291d8f 27.51MB / 27.51MB                                                                                                                                                   0.6s
 => => sha256:48c7067512a645c4cc70a6dda6d41119c7927d074c4ac514c65cc82beaf2026d 21.07MB / 21.07MB                                                                                                                                                   1.1s
 => => sha256:4f4fb700ef54461cfa02571ae0db9a0dc1e0cdb5577484a6d75e68dc38e8acc1 32B / 32B                                                                                                                                                           0.8s
 => => extracting sha256:3823320faa42774534fd7eee0bd245af8cec6a720ad722144d40efa229291d8f                                                                                                                                                          1.8s
 => => extracting sha256:77d1ed2b12f544b45374b498afe9c19b0fa13e347937dc4fde2c45e35dea19af                                                                                                                                                         19.9s
 => => extracting sha256:a2d45245a4b12191026b0c39208107aa1cf1e9c142c3f647ae011dfa383c0995                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:48c7067512a645c4cc70a6dda6d41119c7927d074c4ac514c65cc82beaf2026d                                                                                                                                                          1.1s
 => => extracting sha256:4f4fb700ef54461cfa02571ae0db9a0dc1e0cdb5577484a6d75e68dc38e8acc1                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [2/2] RUN mkdir /tmp/foobar                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.4s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.3s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.2s
 => => writing image sha256:58e38ab0a97ebded0b053c2b218df323701601b3d2e64463a3ace34ec41b32e9                                                                                                                                                       0.0s

As you can see, the 1st build produces sha256 40f6b002363, while the 2nd build produces sha256 58e38ab0a.
Is this normal? Are those 256 not supposed to be purely deterministic given the same input?
My high-level goal is to write Dockerfiles in a way that reusing the docker build-cache across different hosts is possible.

mkdir is not a deterministic command to start with. It creates a folder with a creation time: ctime that will reflect the time the folder was created (you can see that with a stat /tmp/foobar)

Is there a better example command? I was getting the same result with "USER root" instead of "RUN mkdir". Also what I find confusing is that docker is reusing those layers from the cache when building locally again without pruning between the build commands (because the sha256 hashes are then matching).

I think the close vote as "not a programming question" is not justified. High-level, this is a question about writing Dockerfiles in a way that reusing the docker build-cache across different hosts is possible.
